# Blank Page After Odoo Login

Tags: python, odoo

Why do I get blank page after Odoo Login? It was working yesterday but when I tried to open right now, I only get empty page. At first, I thought it was just my directory or the `odoo.conf` is not properly configured.

[image]

This is my Odoo.conf, I paste the full path directory.

```
[options]
admin_passwd = $pbkdf2-sha512$25000$dU5JyZlz7j3nXGsNIeTc.w$cTmFgsasmArJX.s8xSfdb1uoGHLNbpmQVONRbTii2yFUbSUkZ9uCQ6vJpDgfheC9gDSgF6FVYGIYORq1kEZi8w
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = openpg
db_password = openpgpwd
addons_path = odoo  , odoo\addons , customadds , C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\odoo\odoov16\server\addons , C:\Users\emman\OneDrive\Desktop\odoo\odoov16\server\customadds , customadds\estate
http_port = 8100
```

I don't see any error in my terminal.

```
2023-11-04 06:45:39,479 20804 INFO ? odoo: database: openpg@localhost:5432 
2023-11-04 06:45:39,908 20804 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports. 
2023-11-04 06:45:40,388 20804 INFO odoov16 odoo.modules.loading: loading 1 modules... 
2023-11-04 06:45:40,401 20804 INFO odoov16 odoo.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries (+0 extra) 
2023-11-04 06:45:40,454 20804 INFO odoov16 odoo.modules.loading: updating modules list 
2023-11-04 06:45:40,460 20804 INFO odoov16 odoo.addons.base.models.ir_module: ALLOW access to module.update_list on [] to user __system__ #1 via n/a
2023-11-04 06:45:41,256 20804 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on DESKTOP-C4ONJDV:8100 
2023-11-04 06:45:41,425 20804 WARNING odoov16 odoo.modules.module: Missing `license` key in manifest for 'estate', defaulting to LGPL-3 
2023-11-04 06:45:43,401 20804 INFO odoov16 odoo.addons.base.models.ir_module: ALLOW access to module.button_upgrade on ['Real Estate'] to user __system__ #1 via n/a 
2023-11-04 06:45:43,402 20804 INFO odoov16 odoo.addons.base.models.ir_module: ALLOW access to module.update_list on ['Real Estate'] to user __system__ #1 via n/a
2023-11-04 06:45:45,281 20804 INFO odoov16 odoo.addons.base.models.ir_module: ALLOW access to module.button_install on [] to user __system__ #1 via n/a 
2023-11-04 06:45:45,363 20804 INFO odoov16 odoo.modules.loading: loading 66 modules... 
2023-11-04 06:45:45,363 20804 INFO odoov16 odoo.modules.loading: Loading module estate (2/66)
2023-11-04 06:45:45,493 20804 INFO odoov16 odoo.modules.registry: module estate: creating or updating database tables 
2023-11-04 06:45:45,717 20804 INFO odoov16 odoo.modules.loading: loading estate/security/ir.model.access.csv 
2023-11-04 06:45:45,737 20804 INFO odoov16 odoo.modules.loading: loading estate/view/estate_menus.xml 
2023-11-04 06:45:45,754 20804 INFO odoov16 odoo.modules.loading: loading estate/view/estate_property_views.xml 
2023-11-04 06:45:45,819 20804 INFO odoov16 odoo.modules.loading: Module estate loaded in 0.46s, 102 queries (+102 other) 
2023-11-04 06:45:47,262 20804 INFO odoov16 odoo.modules.loading: 66 modules loaded in 1.90s, 102 queries (+102 extra) 
2023-11-04 06:45:47,851 20804 INFO odoov16 odoo.modules.loading: Model test.model is declared but cannot be loaded! (Perhaps a module was partially removed or renamed) 
2023-11-04 06:45:47,858 20804 INFO odoov16 odoo.modules.registry: verifying fields for every extended model
2023-11-04 06:45:48,376 20804 INFO odoov16 odoo.modules.loading: Modules loaded. 
2023-11-04 06:45:48,386 20804 INFO odoov16 odoo.modules.registry: Registry loaded in 8.053s
```

But when I open my console in Browser, I get error 500

[image]

I even opened my pgadmin4 but it still doesn't work

Comment: Remove the module path from addons path `customadds\estate`

Comment: @Kenly, It didn't work

Comment: It wasn't meant to be a solution. Start the server with `-s -c CONFIG_FILE_PATH` to create a config file then add the `customadds` to the addons path

Answer (score 0):

the way your adding addons path is incorrect and i think that is causing the issue.
Kindly replace your config addons path with below and check if it works.

```
addons_path =C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\odoo\odoov16\server\addons
```

if this works for you your issue is that you are not loading the addons path by absolute path.
you have to include it like the one in the code snippet provided.
Hope this helps you